# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken when i am using collection_select in form_for tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am new to ruby on rails.
i am trying to send data selected by select option, but on create action ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken is raised and i can't figure out why.
if i remove collection_select line from form then form submits.

app/views/codes/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @code, url: {action: "create"}, html: {class: "form-horizontal form-bordered"} do |f| %>

<div class="form-body">
<div class="form-group TextBoxContainer">
<label class="control-label col-md-2"> Tracking Code(s) </label>
<div class="col-md-6">
<%= f.text_field :code, name: "[code][]" , class: "form-control",placeholder: "Enter Tracking Code(s) for Analytics" %>
</div>
<div class="actions col-md-4 div_tag">
<button type="button" class="btn dark btn-outline add_another_code">
<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Another Code</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<!-- <%= f.collection_select(:webpage_id,Webpage.all, :id, :title,{prompt: true})%>  -->






<%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn red btn-lg' %>
<% end %>
```

this is my codes_controller.rb

app/assets/controller/codes_controller.rb

```
class CodesController < ApplicationController



def new                 
@code = Code.new

end

def create

debugger

@code = Code.new
@code.webpage_id = params[:webpage_id]
params[:code].each  do |code|
@code.code << code

end

if @code.save

redirect_to '/'

else
render 'new'

end

end


def edit
@code = Code.find(params[:id])
end

def update 


   @code = Code.find(params[:id])


   if @code.update(code_params)

    redirect_to '/'
  else
    render 'edit'
  end

end







private


def code_params
params.require(:code).permit(:webpage_id,code:[])

end

end
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an `authenticity_token: true` parameter to your form?

Comment: yes, i added authenticity_token: true to form, but still ActionController is raising invalid authenticity error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<%= f.select :webpage_id, Webpage.all.map {|c| [c.title, c.id] }, {prompt:"Choose Webpage"} %>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: @mohitkumar can u submit it, without `collect_select`, Does it save ? Also do u have `webpage_id` in your `Code` table ?

Comment: @TobySpeight kinda the problem is not in `select`. Ill change it once fix it.

Comment: yes @7urkm3n the form submits and data gets saved without collection_select and i have webpage_id in Code model.

Comment: @mohitkumar also in your `create` method. its supposed to be `params[:code][:webpage_id]` and `params[:code][:code]`